# Reference for quotient stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

I would like to understand stacks, but the general theory seems pretty abstract to me and I would be happy to limit myself to the case of a quotient stack $[X/G]$.

Are there introductory notes that focus on such stacks ?

Comment: I'm no expert, but the introductions [What is a.. Stack](http://faculty.missouri.edu/~edidind/Papers/whatisastack.pdf) by Eddin and [Stacks for Everybody](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8268-2_20) by Fantechi are pretty readable. Obviously the big reference is the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look at the lecture notes on the website of Michael Groechenig.

```
http://individual.utoronto.ca/groechenig/stacks.html
```

Comment: That looks pretty good. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can also look at these notes by Daniel Halpern-Leistner http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~danielhl/moduli_theory_notes.pdf